# Filtering pandas Series with a condition on the elements of a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I want to filter my Series based on a condition on the elements of a list. I did this but it returns "Invalid syntax". crtitc1 is my DataFrame and elem1 is my list.

```
critic1 = critic1.loc[critic1["deltaP"] >= elem1[i] for i in range(len(elem1))]
```

Is there any method to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The comparison operators of Series can use lists as reference.

Assuming equal length of critic1 and elem1, you should be able to do:

```
critic1 = critic1.loc[critic1["deltaP"] >= elem1]
```

Or if elem1 is longer than critic1["deltaP"]:

```
critic1 = critic1.loc[critic1["deltaP"] >= elem1[:len(critic1)]]
```

If critic1["deltaP"] is longer than elem1 and you want to drop the last rows, you could try:

```
m = critic1["deltaP"].iloc[:len(elem1)] > elem1

critic1.loc[m[m].index]
```

##### alternative understanding of the question

test if elements of critic1["deltaP"] are in elem1:

Use `isin`:

```
critic1[critic1["deltaP"].isin(elem1)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The fact is critic1["deltaP"] is longer than elem1. Is it possible to test all the elements of the list for each critic1["deltaP"] value, avoiding "for" boucle ?

Comment: @Jorisltc let me know if this works. If not, please update the question with a minimal example of the data and the eventual error traceback

Comment: If `critic1["deltaP"]` is longer what do you want to do with the extra elements? drop them? check the update

Comment: I am comparing two electrical powers. I want to save the minutes (included in my dataframe critics1) corresponding to the powers deltaP (included in my dataframe) which are superior to at least one element of my list. If this element exists, I should delete it from my list and stop my research once my list is empty.

Comment: Thank you, it works with what you write if critic1["deltaP"] is longer than elem1 !

Comment: @Jorisltc which one works?